# Laravel : Create Show More Button using pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

As the title says,
How would you create a "Show More" button using Laravel Paginate

```
$model->links("pagination::simple");
```

doesn't do the trick because it should only show *next* button.

Comment: This isn't really a Laravel issue. I'm assuming you want to load in more results without changing the page? You can implement this yourself using HTML and Javascript. Perform an AJAX request to bring in the next set of results and use Javascript to generate the HTML for them

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to show all results when user clicks on "Show More" button. In this case I recommend you to make another query and just show the results without pagination.